# Don´t see template-upload with add : jqueryfileupload config

Tags: jquery-file-upload

Why can't I see the template-upload when I use add: in the fileUpload config

It doesn't work when add the option add: function(){}

```js
$('#formpublicacion').fileupload({
 dataType: 'json',
 url: 'publicaciones/',
 add: function (e, data){
 $("#publicar").on('click', function () {
       data.submit();
    });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced by this code

```js
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        var that = this;
      //add this line
     $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.add.call(that, e, data);
        $("#up_btn").on('click', function () {
            data.submit();
        });
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```